# How do I isolate changes for promotion to environment branches?

Tags: git

I'm working on a repository whose applications are published to three different environments (Development, UAT and Production). The consulting company that set up the repository went with three branches (I'll call them "environment branches"), one for each environment. In other words, the `uat` branch has the code that is built and deployed to the UAT environment, `dev` has the code for Development and `main` the code for Production.

Furthermore, the consultants created a workflow such that topic branches are merged (squash-committed) onto `dev`, then the code is promoted to UAT by merging from `dev` to `uat` (no-fast-forward merge), finally it is promoted to Production by merging from `uat` to `main` (no-fast-forward merge). Topic branches are deleted upon merging to `dev`. Occasional hotfixes are handled by committing straight to `dev`, then cherry-picking the relevant commit(s) straight to `main`.

This approach is causing some issues. The main drawback is that everything has got to be promoted in a single batch, otherwise you need to cherry pick. If we have three changes in UAT and one of them is not approved for promotion, then we cannot promote the other two, unless we cherry pick, which is error-prone and quite frankly ugly: why would we have to "cherry pick" the 90% (say) of the changes when we actually want to "cherry throw away" the rejected 10%? This has already forced us to delay deployments and releases, which is not being received favorably.

Also, all this cherry-picking of hotfixes is making the log harder to read, and it skips the pull request workflow, thus reducing documentation and control. Plus, even ignoring cherry-picking, the pull requests that promote changes to `uat` and `main` are actually less meaningful, because they just bunch several unrelated changes together into a single "promotion" pull request.

I'm being tasked with finding a solution to the delayed release issue, which is becoming more and more blocking because the repository hosts several projects and a failed UAT test in one of the projects is actually holding all the other projects from receiving the new approved changes. My approach would be to keep the topic branches alive "beyond `dev`", and merging them into each of the environment branches independently. This way, a rejected change for Project A in UAT will not move on to Production, but a change for Project B will still be allowed to be merged into UAT, tested, approved and promoted to Production independently.

Of course, hotfixes should also be handled with topic branches, they would just move faster up the promotion ladder.

When I casually discussed the issue with the consultants a few weeks ago, they said that "it was complicated" to find a good solution because the projects in the repository depend on each other (there is a UI project, several services and a few libraries). I don't think this is an issue with my proposed solution, because each topic branch would be self-contained and handle the necessary dependencies, but they seem not inclined to go this way, even though they have refused to elaborate why.

My approach would also improve the pull request documentation: while there would be many more PRs than we have now, one could open the PR that merged a topic branch into `main` and immediately understand what went on in Production.

The consultants' resistance and my own little experience with enterprise-scale Git workflows makes me hesitant to support my proposal. **What is a good** (safe, easy to document, flexible) **approach to managing multiple environments in Git?** **What are the main cons of my proposed solution?**

**Alternatively**, I'd go with a model that I've seen discussed in several places, in which promotions are handled by branching from the target environment branch, thus making something like a release branch, which would then be merged back into the environment branch itself. This has the advantage of not polluting the environment branch with a change that may not move on to further promotion (like Project A's rejected change in my previous example), but it seems more cumbersome to me and I'm not sure it's worth the effort.

I'm also not sure how a promotion would work. In my initial proposal, the branch `my-feature` would be merged into `dev`, then into `uat` and eventually into `main`, with the three environment branches eventually sharing the same history (but I'm not sure what would happen in case of a non-promoted change, or if changes were promoted out of order). In this model instead I'd have to branch a `promotion/uat/my-feature` from `uat`, and then merge from `my-feature` to `promotion/uat/my-feature` - but can I even do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *"cherry throw away" the rejected 10%*
  I guess if you're brave enough you could make that easier by temporarily removing the 10% you don't need, instead of cherry-picking the branches you need.
  Say you want to promote `dev` to `uat` but **without** `topicX`,
  which was already merged into `dev`,
  **before** promotion.
  Run
  `git revert -m1 <commit-id(s)-of-topicX-merge>` on `dev` to remove
  the changes of `topicX`.
  Merge `dev` into
  `uat`.
  **After** promotion use `git revert <revert-commit-ids...>`
  to revert the resulting revert-commits from the previous step on
  `dev`, in order to restore `topicX` on `dev`.
  This way the changes
  will be available in a potential future promotion.

---

A workflow that you suggested (topic branches don't die and get merged, not cherry-picked or squashed) is actually was I use day by day. Some of the disadvantages that I consider mention-worthy:

- **Topic-branches must be based on commits common to *all* environment-branches**,
  otherwise they could introduce foreign commits when being merged.
  We solve that by creating new topic-branches on top of `main`.
  Additonally we merge `main` back into `uat` and `dev` after releases - which should usually be a no-op - to re-unify the code-base/commit-history and make future merging easier for git and us.
  Also: If `topicX` requires changes that are not on `main` yet, it has to merge the topic-branches that introduced those changes into its own branch. For example maybe it needs classes provided by `topicY` and `topicZ`.
  That dependency should then be documented in the ticketing system.
  Merging `topicX` will also merge all its dependencies, that means it must be documented that `topicX` must not be promoted before `topicY` and `topicZ` get promoted.
- **More merges. More merge conflicts. Re-occuring merge-conflicts**,
  that *should* be solved the same way.
  As you'll have to merge more often, there will also be more merge-conflicts to solve. Conflicts during merges on `dev` might re-occur when merging on `uat` and `main`.
  And worst of all: Those merges should be resolved on `uat` the same way as on `dev`. Same goes for *main*. Otherwise you'll run into even more merge-conflicts in future or unintended changes in behavior will occur during such promotion.
  Experience has shown that people occasionally don't pay enough attention (or just have different number or content of merge-conflicts, based on the merge-order of the topic-branches).
  Sometimes a topic-branch that was merged into *dev* will be merged differently into *uat*, etc.
  Especially when under pressure people like to neglect their diligence.
  However if you're *usually* going to just merge the entire `dev` branch into `uat` (if such a merge is an option to begin with), rather than single topic-branches, then I guess that isn't as big of a problem.
- **Merge-graphs from hell**,
  which can lead to confusion, performance issues and other issues.
  Having a complete merge history for every single branch is nice, but it comes with a price. The merge graphs may become considerably wider (based on how much parallel/long-term development is going on).
  You may end up with `git log --graph` being wider than your screen when scrolling down.
  This will also cause programs like git-kraken to struggle when trying to display (or make sense of) the commit history. Slowing down in the process and slowly eating away at your soul.
- **Git may have problems recognizing file renames**, leading to slow or "weird" merges.
  This is not a big deal as you can always specify `-Xno-renames` or set your default to not considering them.
  But if you *do* need to track renames (because a file name/folder often get changed in one branch and its contents changed in another branch), then this might not be practical.

---

That being said, I personally do like that workflow in *our* context, where issues and topic-branches are usually promoted individually. Also having a complete history on main and being able to directly `git bisect` on it down to individual commits is *occasionally* kind of nice.
However, it does lead to a higher level of convolution and complication and therefore requires more time, diligence, understanding and (as much as I don't like to say it) intelligence on behalf of the people working with it.
That's why we're eventually might change to using squashed cherry-picks for promotions too. Or try to come up with something else that's not as big of a headache in practice.
After all, I guess, the git workflow shouldn't require that much attention and energy from those working with it.
Especially if isn't *really* worth it.

Comment: This is what we ended up doing. It is virtually trunk-based development, but with two additional environment branches, each representing Development and UAT, that only receive merges (actually squash commits) from the feature branches. Seems to work fine.